# Automating time-series dates update

Tags: r, automation, time-series

A reproducible example:
Suppose we have a time series for an indicator that is updated on quarterly basis as in Table 1.

```
Quarter Indicator
2010-1  11
2010-2  14
2010-3  15
2010-4  12
2011-1  11
2011-2  18
2011-3  15
2011-4  19
2012-1  14
2012-2  15
2012-3  18
2012-4  16
```

This time-series is disaggregated to monthly basis using the following code:

> z <- read.zoo(data, FUN = function(x) as.yearqtr(x, "%Y-%q"))

> ind_month <- zooreg(na.approx(c(t(cbind(z, NA, NA)))),
> start = as.yearmon(start(z)), freq = 12)
>
> new_data <- fortify.zoo(ind_month)

Now, there are a series of predictors that are produced on monthly basis that are used to predict the time-series. For simplicity, let us consider two predictors as follows:

```
Predictor1  Predictor2
12  5
14  4
11  8
7   2
9   6
0   9
15  11
2   6
6   8
12  9
11  14
9   16
4   12
5   3
6   5
2   3
7   8
0   11
3   16
2   18
5   15
6   18
4   16
7   22
3   17
2   9
2   18
7   16
6   14
2   13
5   17
4   12
9   9
6   18
2   6
9   17
4   15
6   13
0   17
```

In the second table, the number of months can exceed the number of months in Table 1 after disaggregation. This is due the fact that quarterly data needs to have three months to be updated. While the predictors are updated monthly. There are two issues that I need to solve:
1-  After disaggregating Table 1, I need the number of months produced to match the length of table 2. For the indicator variable, the additional data will be missing NA. Which is fine, as we want to predict these values.
2-  The other problem, table 2 updates every month with a new row for Predictors 1 and 2. How to tell are to increase the time index by one month to match table 2. And if the issue in part 1 is solved, I think the problem in the second point will be solved as the analysis can be re-run with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Automation is a topic of its own and stands besides R. Are you on a Unix or Windows environment? In Unix, you might want to look into [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

The R part of your question can be answered more straightforward. I understand that you basically want to bind two tables together.

```
data.frame(Index = c("Jan 2021", "Feb 2021"), values = c(15, 14)) -> df_old
data.frame(Index = c("Mar 2021"), values = c(14)) -> df_new

rbind(df_old, df_new)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The method you are proposing is if I do have two data frames and all I want is just to bind them by row. However, the second data frame only contains values with no dates. Therefore, I need to bind it by row and autocomplete the dates. This is the main challenge. For instance, the second data frame may contain five rows for five months but without dates. When I want to attach it to the first data frame, the index file that contain dates should autocomplete the time-series dates.

Comment: Ok, can you upload a reproducable example of the exact format?

Comment: I have modified my original question now. I hope it is clearer.